# Opposite of \ensuremath: ensure that I'm *not* in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, conditionals

I'd like a macro that is the opposite of `\ensuremath`: something like `\ensurenotmath`, which makes sure that its argument is *not* typeset in math mode. Is there such a macro, or a way to implement it?

For my purposes, it would be sufficient to just detect math mode, so I could do something like:

```
\if\inmathmode
    % give sensible error message
\else
    % do the usual thing
\fi
```

Any ideas?

(Alternatively: I tried `\show\ensuremath` to see how it works, but it's protected. How can I use `\show` on such a macro?)

Comment: morbusg answered your real question. For the second question, protected macros come are defined by expanding to `\protect\foo ` where there is actually a space in the name `\foo `. You can use `\expandafter\show\csname foo \endcsname`--note the space after foo--to see the definition.

Comment: Also, you can use `\mbox{...}` and the ... will be typeset in restricted horizontal mode, no matter what mode you're in outside the `\mbox`.

Comment: @TH: thanks for the tip about `\expandafter` and `\csname`!

Comment: You could also use the [`texdef`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texdef) script: `texdef -t latex ensuremath` (or `latexdef ensuremath` if the `latedef` symlink to `texdef` was created). It detects the protected status automatically and also show the macro with the space. You can also use it explicitly: `texdef -t latex 'ensuremath '`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`\ifmmode <do_something>\else <do_something_else>\fi`

Comment: Heh, you beat me by 2 seconds.

Comment: @TH.: Haha, I know the feeling

Comment: Ack! I found `\ifmmode` right after posting this question. Thanks for the super-quick answer.

Comment: Note, however, that if you reliably want to _escape_ from math mode to text then you need to use an `\mbox`. This is nicely wrapped up by the `amstext` package as the `\text` macro.

Answer (score 20):

Simply using `\text{}` should ensure that you are not in math mode?

Joseph makes a very good point about `text{}` not being unrestricted horizontal mode, so the above will work only for short text snippets that don't need to cross line boundaries. I think a better solution would be:

`\parbox{\linewidth}{}`

Comment: Note that this will be a box: you can't use this to get into unrestricted horizontal mode.