# Strikeout in math mode

Tags: math-mode, strikeout

How can I strikeout words in math mode (similar to `\sout` with `\usepackage{ulem}` in text mode)? I've tried `\usepackage{cancel}` and `\(\cancel{1+1=2}\)` but that draws a diagonal line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use something like

```
\sout{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}
```

or

```
\[
  \hbox{\sout{$a^2+b^2$}}=c^2
\]
```

And you can of course define a command for convenience.

Comment: This does not work inside math mode, e.g. if I want to strikeout a portion of a phrase in math mode.

Comment: @N.N.: It's easy to generalize the solution. See update.

Comment: This method does not really work well. The `ulem` package is necessary, and it changes `\emph{}` to underlining.

Comment: @Jeff: Use `\normalem`.

Comment: @Jeff: or `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`.

Answer (score 25):

version 2 (fine remark from Martin)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor,cancel}

\newcommand\hcancel[2][black]{\setbox0=\hbox{$#2$}%
\rlap{\raisebox{.45\ht0}{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\wd0}{1pt}}}}#2} 

\begin{document}

\[
  x+\hcancel[red]{ \sum_a \mathcal{D}^a\mathcal{D}_a}=2x+ \sum_a \mathcal{D}^a\mathcal{D}_a+3 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\hbox{#2}` will typeset `#2` in textmode, which is fine with `y` (except maybe a slightly wrong width), but will break horrible with real math expressions.

Comment: @Martin yes you are right, I forgot `$...$`

Comment: Does this solution rely on `\documentclass{scrartcl}`?

Comment: @N.N. no I think the package `cancel is independent

Comment: I removed the `$$` from the `\hbox` and included them in the parameter (e.g., `\hcancel{$2+2=4$}` and it worked fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to make it work also in subscript? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583242/colored-strikeout-in-subscript-in-mathmode

Answer (score 21):

I'm using this hack with the `ulem` package in the preamble.

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\stkout}[1]{\ifmmode\text{\sout{\ensuremath{#1}}}\else\sout{#1}\fi}
```

In the document, I use the command thus defined, `\stkout`

```
Lorem \stkout{ipsum}. $x + \stkout{y + z} = 1$.
\begin{equation}
    A + \stkout{B + C + D} = E.
\end{equation}
```

[image: Screen capture of the example document]

Reference: [Opposite of \ensuremath: ensure that I'm *not* in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15193/opposite-of-ensuremath-ensure-that-im-not-in-math-mode)

Comment: If find the `cancel` package much more practical, but your method is anyway interesting  :)

Comment: I quite like this approach, but feel that it would work better by just patching this to `\sout` - you can do this with `\let\isout\sout` `\renewcommand{\sout}[1]{\ifmmode\text{\isout{\ensuremath{#1}}}\else\isout{#1}\fi}` in the premable of your document. Requires amsmath and ulem

Comment: Calling the ulem package seems to have unintended consequences for my bibliography. :(.

Comment: Why does this preserve italics even though the math is inside \text?

Answer (score 13):

Works in math and text mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newsavebox\CBox
\newcommand\hcancel[2][0.5pt]{%
  \ifmmode\sbox\CBox{$#2$}\else\sbox\CBox{#2}\fi%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox\CBox}%  
  \rule[0.5\ht\CBox-#1/2]{\wd\CBox}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\hcancel{Test}
\hcancel[2pt]{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, but you need to restart the mathmode, don't you? E.g. `$x+\hcancel{$y$}+z$.