# How to type a slash through a letter?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/how-to-strike-through-obliquely-e-g-to-indicate-cancellation)

How can I type a slash through a letter (specifically an 'R' as in 'not related to') in math mode? Thanks.

Comment: Use the `cancel` package with `\cancel{R}`.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40254/10898 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20609/10898

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.