# How do I strike out indices?

Tags: formatting, subscripts, superscripts, strikeout

I want to strike out the superscripts and subscripts for an expression like 
$$\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$$

I tried the ulem package:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\sout{Hello World}
```

and the soul package

```
\usepackage{soul}
\st{Hello World}
```

But neither of worked.

**My Question**

How do I strike out indices?

Comment: The [`cancel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) might suit your needs better.

Comment: I checked breifly the answers in the other question and it seems to me that they'll all fail to use the correct font size.

Comment: Wait... why you deleted your explanation of duplicate? You think Maarten Dhondt's asnwer is good enough? By the way @yo' is Maarten Dhondt's answer using the correct font size?

Comment: @Symbol1 Ah it does. But the reason why is very strange, and the answer will likely fail in some cases, since the measurements are based on completely wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is mentioned in [Strikeout in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20609/strikeout-in-math-mode)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\newcommand\hcancel[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
\rlap{\raisebox{.45\ht0}{\rule{\wd0}{1pt}}}#1} 

\begin{document}

\[
  \Gamma^{\hcancel{\lambda}}_{\hcancel{\mu\nu}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...then it's a duplicate, right?

Comment: Seems that way, yes