# Strikeout and qtree

Tags: trees, strikeout

I cannot get strikeout to apply inside a `tikzpicture`. In the example below, strikeout only applies to"Hello World" at the beginning, but not in the tree. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\sout{Hello World}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.CP{$\langle t\rangle$} [.DP{$\langle e,t\rangle, t\rangle$} \node(wh){something}; ]
[.C$'${$<$(e$_{3}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$), \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack e$_{2}$ \rbrack$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack \sout{Hello World} \thinspace e$_{3}$ \rbrack$ $>$ } [.C $\lambda$ ]
[.\node[draw]{{$<$t$_{1}$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack e$_{2}$ \rbrack$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack e$_{3}$ \rbrack$ $>$ }}; 
[.\node[draw]{e$_{2}$ }; ]
[.{$<$(e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$), \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack e$_{3}$ \rbrack$ $>$} [.{$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack \emptyset \rbrack$ $>$}  {$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack \emptyset \rbrack$ $>$} ]
[.\node[draw]{e$_{3}$ }; 
[. e$_{3}$; ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is not the `tree`, the problem is with math mode. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20609/strikeout-in-math-mode. By the way, your example should include `\usepackage{ulem}`