# Wrong to delete/replace equation by using changes package

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathtools, changes

I am using changes package to check the changing in my latex file. For changing in sentence, it works well. However, it showed some wrong/unexpected result when I change equation. This is my problem and my code. Could you look at this and give me a way to solve it? Thank all

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{changes}

\begin{document}
I want to delete $y=1$ look likes \deleted{$y=1$ }.
But it was failure in dcase
And replace $z=x+1$ to $z=y+1$ as \replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.
However, the case equation has error as:

\begin{equation}\hspace{0pt}\label{eq:1}
\begin{dcases}
x=1\\
\deleted{y=1}
\\
\replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.
\end{dcases}
\hfill\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Update: this is example to show unexpected result by using cancel package

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\setdeletedmarkup{\cancel{#1}}

\begin{document}
I want to delete $y=1$ look likes \deleted{$y=1$ }.
But it was failure in dcase. And replace $z=x+1$ to $z=y+1$ as \replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.\deleted{This is long sentence which I want to delete}, However, it showed wrong location to delete by using cancel package
However, the case equation has error as:

\begin{equation}\hspace{0pt}\label{eq:1}
\begin{dcases}
x=1\\
\deleted{y=1}
\\
\replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.
\end{dcases}
\hfill\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: cancelling as such is typographically problematic. Avoid using it but instead use colors. Or strikethrough

Comment: @percusse: How can i obtain the the result in equation as in text by using strikethrough

Comment: It is not straightforward, I always change the opacity of the deleted text for the articles etc.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Marijn's solution in combination with Cong Ma's `\sout` [hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20609/strikeout-in-math-mode) which works pretty well in order to enforce horizontal strikeouts within and outside math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\stkout}[1]{\ifmmode\text{\sout{\ensuremath{#1}}}\else\sout{#1}\fi}
\setdeletedmarkup{\stkout{#1}}

\begin{document}
I want to delete $y=1$ look likes \deleted{$y=1$ }.
But it was failure in dcase
And replace $z=x+1$ to $z=y+1$ as \replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.
However, the case equation has error as:

\begin{equation}\hspace{0pt}\label{eq:1}
\begin{dcases}
x=1\\
\deleted{y=1}
\\
\replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.
\end{dcases}
\hfill\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note: The `cancel` package is not needed here.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to settle for diagonal lines then you can use the `cancel` package (which works inside equations) as a user-defined markup for `changes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\setdeletedmarkup{\cancel{#1}}

\begin{document}
I want to delete $y=1$ look likes \deleted{$y=1$ }.
But it was failure in dcase
And replace $z=x+1$ to $z=y+1$ as \replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.
However, the case equation has error as:

\begin{equation}\hspace{0pt}\label{eq:1}
\begin{dcases}
x=1\\
\deleted{y=1}
\\
\replaced{z=y+1}{z=x+1}.
\end{dcases}
\hfill\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but cancel package is not good to delete the sentence, It takes so much space

Comment: @user8430 what do you mean exactly? It looks like the strikethrough with `cancel` takes the same space as the default strikethrough in `changes` when you look at the two screenshots in this question.

Comment: @Marijin: Sorry for reply late. I update the example in my question. It shows unexpected result by using the diagonal line