# Redefine `changes` macros to play nicely with `amsmath` `\text{}`

Tags: macros, amsmath, changes

I am using the `changes` package to highlight changes in my document. But changes inside math mode throw errors when listing the changes, so I tried wrapping them in `\ensuremath{}`. I thought it would be convenient to redefine the macros to automate this. The issue is that it does not always work in both `draft` and `final` modes (see MWE below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\def\mode{draft}
%\def\mode{final}

\usepackage[\mode]{changes}

% My attempt
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mode}{draft}}{
    \let\origreplaced\replaced
    \renewcommand{\replaced}[2]{\ifmmode{\origreplaced{\ensuremath{#1}}{\ensuremath{#2}}}
                                \else{\origreplaced{#1}{#2}}\fi}
}{}

\begin{document}
    Deleting \deleted{some undesirable} text

    % Worked originally - inspiration for redefinition
    % \[ K = \alpha^2\replaced{\ensuremath{\phi_\text{in}}}{\ensuremath{\phi_\text{out}}} \]

    % Works
    \[ K = \alpha^2\replaced{\phi_{\text{in}}}{\phi_{\text{out}}} \]
    
    \[
    \begin{aligned}
        % Does not work
        \replaced{\phi_{\text{in}}}{\phi_{\text{out}}}
        &= \frac{1}{A} \int T(\vec{x})\,\mathrm{d}\vec{x} \\
        &= \frac{1}{\pi R_2^2} \int_{R_1}^{R_2}T(r) 2\pi r\,\mathrm{d}r
    \end{aligned}
    \]
    
    \listofchanges

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to redefine the macros so that I do not need to use `\ensuremath{}` each time? I am not very proficient in LaTeX, but I tried playing with `\protect`, `\expandafter` etc., but could not manage to make it work. Of course, solutions without `\ensuremath{}` are definitely welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this post  [Correct usage of \ifmmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82653/correct-usage-of-ifmmode), it requires a `\relax` before `\ifmmode`

```
\renewcommand{\replaced}[2]{\relax\ifmmode{\origreplaced{\ensuremath{#1}}
```

With this other post [Wrong to delete/replace equation by using changes package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297111/wrong-to-delete-replace-equation-by-using-changes-package/352748#352748), we can steer in math mode

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\def\mode{draft}
%\def\mode{final}

\usepackage[\mode]{changes}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297111/wrong-to-delete-replace-equation-by-using-changes-package/352748#352748
% My attempt
\newcommand{\stkout}[1]{\ifmmode\text{\sout{\ensuremath{#1}}}\else\sout{#1}\fi}
\setdeletedmarkup{\stkout{#1}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82653/correct-usage-of-ifmmode

\ifthenelse{\equal{\mode}{draft}}{
    \let\origreplaced\replaced
    \renewcommand{\replaced}[2]{\relax\ifmmode{\origreplaced{\ensuremath{#1}}{\ensuremath{#2}}}\else{\origreplaced{#1}{#2}}\fi}
}{}
\begin{document}
    Deleting \deleted{some undesirable} text

    \[ K = \alpha^2\replaced{\phi_{\text{in}}}{\phi_{\text{out}}}\]
    
    \[
    \begin{aligned}
        \replaced{\phi_{\text{in}}}{\phi_{\text{out}}}
        &= \frac{1}{A} \int T(\vec{x})\,\mathrm{d}\vec{x} \\
        &= \frac{1}{\pi R_2^2} \int_{R_1}^{R_2}T(r) 2\pi r\,\mathrm{d}r
    \end{aligned}
    \]
    
    \listofchanges
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I had already stumbled upon both the questions linked before asking the question myself, and I was also using the hack to get strikeout working in both math mode and text mode, but was not TeX-savvy ;) enough to understand how `\relax`, `\protect` etc. work and implement this myself. Accepting the answer. Thanks!