# How to strike through in mbox and in begin{Large}?

Tags: strikeout

[image]

**Here is my input here.**

I want strikrthrough all these lines

(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+

(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+

1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage[left=8mm,top=6mm,bottom=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

 \begin{document}

\[
\mbox{
\Large$
\st{
(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2
}
$}
\]
\st{
\begin{Large}
\begin{align*}
&(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+
\\
&(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+
\\
&1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
\end{align*}
\end{Large}
}

\[
  \hbox{\sout{$&(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+
\\
 &  (-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+
\\
 &1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)$}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you want to achieve? For instance, `\[
\mbox{
 \Large
 \st{
(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2
}}
\]` works, but I do not know if this is what you want to get. You will also need to load `amsmath` if you want to use `align*`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, Can  `nccmath` replace `amsmath`?

Comment: OK, good point! But I still do not know what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I've edited my post. I hope you can understand me now

Comment: Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20609 ?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, \[
  \hbox{\sout{$&(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+
\\
 &  (-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+
\\
 &1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)$}}
\] it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Large
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \st{$(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+{}$}\\
    \st{$(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+{}$}\\
    \st{$1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)$}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you fix `hbox`?

Comment: @kile - I'm not sure why you would want to employ an extremely-low-level command such as `\hbox` directly. Can you give a use case? Put differently: Why would you *not* want to employ a `tabular` environment?

Comment: how can I employ `tabular` in this example?

Comment: @kile - The answer I gave employs a `tabular` environment. Please clarify your question.

Comment: -`\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` `\[
  \hbox{\sout{$&(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+\]`

Comment: @kile - `\[ \begin{tabular}{l} \sout{$(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+$} \end{tabular} \]` instead of `\[ \hbox{\sout{$(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+$}} \]`.