# How to make a line (a horizontal line) in an expression in LaTeX?

Tags: line, horizontal

My question regards something like in integral with a horizontal line in the middle of an integral sign, but I want to make this horizontal line inside some an expression (or being more specific inside an alphabet letter).

How to make it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you seek, and show some code you have tried?

Comment: Maybe `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\st{A} \st{$\int$}
\end{document}`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks! looks good to me unless someone has a better horizontal line inside a letter. You can post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: This was more to gauge what you are looking for. Maybe the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20609) are more suitable than the above. Basically you need some extra efforts in math mode. (If you are using Ti*k*Z then there are arguably less hacky solutions with the `tikzmark` library.)