# Colored strikeout in subscript in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, strikeout

In order to strike text in red in math mode, I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20613/116348) quite useful. However, it fails when I want to do it in subscript, since the command does not detect that the size of the text is smaller. Therefore, it overlaps on the content written after, like here:

[image]

Any idea how to strike text in red in math mode in a subscript?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\hcancel[2][black]{\setbox0=\hbox{$#2$}%
   \rlap{\raisebox{.25\ht0}{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\wd0}{1pt}}}}#2}

\begin{document}

$ABC_{\hcancel[red]{DEF}\textcolor{green!50!black}{GHI}}(JKL)$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the command to use the current math style with `\ThisStyle` and `\SavedStyle` from `scalerel`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\hcancel[2][black]{%
    \ThisStyle{%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle #2$}%
        \rlap{\raisebox{.25\ht0}{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\wd0}{1pt}}}}\SavedStyle #2}%
    }
\begin{document}
$ABC_{\hcancel[red]{DEF}\textcolor{green!50!black}{GHI}}(JKL)$
\end{document}
```